# Trying to return tuple

Tags: haskell, tuples

So I'm trying to make game of nim while playing against the computer in haskell as part of an assignment, but I'm struggling with the computer part. what i wish to do is return a tuple containing the heap number(row) and number to remove. So far I've got this:

```
ai board [] = []
ai board (x:xs) = 
    do
       let target = foldr (^) board
       if target < x then do
          let num = x-target   
          return (x, num)
       else
          ai board xs
```

which raises this error:

```
Oblig3.hs:75:1: error:
    * Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Ord (t b -> b)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * When checking the inferred type
        ai :: forall (t :: * -> *) b.
              (Ord (t b -> b), Foldable t, Integral b, Num (t b -> b)) =>
              b -> [t b -> b] -> [(t b -> b, t b -> b)]
   |
75 | ai board [] = []
```

PS board is a list of ints showing how many elements is left in the heap and the computer algorithm is based on the one found on [Nim's wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim?fbclid=IwAR2IkFXSE67kg9NLQacD6MG7xnvYCCMMEkTLSyAWMd1yGAgaJZQr0DphigY#Example_implementation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foldr` takes 3 arguments, but in `target = foldr (^) board`, you're only giving it 2. You can't then compare it with `if target < x` because it's not a number yet, but still a function waiting for one more argument.